# How can I label feature using sld file in geoserver for symbols?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I generate the sld file from Qgis and upload it to the geoserver. My `sld` file looks like following,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.0.0" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <UserLayer>
    <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
      <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
    </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>PGA_100_reclass</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
            <sld:ChannelSelection>
              <sld:GrayChannel>
                <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
              </sld:GrayChannel>
            </sld:ChannelSelection>
            <sld:ColorMap type="values">
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="1" label="Low: PGA < 0.015, MMI < 5" color="#00b04f"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="2" label="Moderate: PGA 0.015 - 0.047, MMI 6 - 7" color="#ffbf00"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="3" label="High: PGA 0.047 - 0.149, MMI 8 - 9" color="#ff0000"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="4" label="Very high: PGA > 0.149, MMI > 10" color="#a80000"/>
            </sld:ColorMap>
          </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </UserLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The layer working fine until I updated my sld file. While I tried to validate this `sld`, it popup with  following error,

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 63; The value of attribute "label" associated with an element type "sld:ColorMapEntry" must not contain the '<' character.
```

I know this mean I can't use "<" and ">" sign in `sld:ColorMapEntry`. But is there any possible way to add these symbol in label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `<` and `>` can't appear inside an XML element as they are confused with starting and ending a tag. So, you must "encode" them as [XML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) in this case `<` is `&lt;` and `>` is `&gt;`.